# setting a Drop down filled to it's value and text on edit mode in AngularJS and asp.net webApi

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I want to autofill field the form with it's right content when the user is editing a particular information

this is the Html content

```
 //Html  content
   <select class="form-control" id="pcategory" ng-model="pcategory" ng-options="c.CID as c.Name for c in pcategoryA">
        <option value="">-- Select Category --</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="name" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" ng-model="price" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" ng-model="quantity" />
```

this is the angularJS implemetation

```
// angularJS
         $http.get('/api/product/' + $routeParams.id).success(function (data)
        {

            $scope.pcategory = data.pcategory.CID , // is an object { "CID":1, "Name": "Solid""}
            $scope.name = data.name,
            $scope.price = data.price,
            $scope.quantity = data.quantity

        });
```

All the field are set except the drop down 
        Can someone help please!

Answer (score 0):

Add a track by to the ng-options

```
<select class="form-control" id="pcategory" ng-model="pcategory" ng-options="c as c.name for c in pcategoryA track by c.CID">
    <option value="">-- Select Category --</option>
</select>
```

And I think you need to switch the model for the id to the full object (not c.CID in the ng-options)
And when setting the $scope variable pcategory set it like so:

```
 $scope.pcategory = {
'CID': 4,
'name': 'name 4'
```

};

I created a codepen to describe.  http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/GZvmQE

Comment: Anyway I was able to solve it with this tricks
$scope.pcategory = ""+data.CID+"",